# Rails Serializer Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a `Component` class that can be either a `Section` or `Question`. A `Section` can have many `Component` (i.e. `Question`).

I'm trying to get the serializer to send back the `Component`(`Section`) and its associated `Component`(`Question`). Right now, based on my code below, I'm getting back the `Question` and the `Section` object that it's associated to (see below). How can I get the serializer to return what I'm expecting?

**Response (current):**

```
{"data":
  [{"id": 1,
    "type": "Section",
    "content": "ABC",
    "section_id": null,
    "section": null
   },
   {"id": 2,
    "type": "Question",
    "content": "Q1",
    "section_id": 1,
    "section": 
      {"id": 1,
       "type": "Section",
       "content": "ABC",
       "section_id": null
      }
   },
   {"id": 3,
    "type": "Question",
    "content": "Q2",
    "section_id": 1,
    "section": 
      {"id": 1,
       "type": "Section",
       "content": "ABC",
       "section_id": null
      }
   }]
}
```

**Response (expected):**

```
{"data":
  [{"id": 1,
    "type": "Section",
    "content": "ABC",
    "section_id": null,
    "section": 
       {"id": 2,
        "type": "Question",
        "content": "Q1",
        "section_id": 1
       },
       {"id": 3,
        "type": "Question",
        "content": "Q2",
        "section_id": 1
       }
   }]
}
```

**ComponentSerializer:**

```
class ComponentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  belongs_to :section

  attributes :id,
         :type,
         :content,
         :section_id
end
```

**SectionSerializer:**

```
class ComponentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  has_many :components

  attributes :id,
         :type,
         :content,
         :section_id
end
```

**component.rb (model):**

```
class Component < ApplicationRecord

  # == Associations ==========================
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :section,
    class_name: 'Section',
    foreign_key: :section_id,
    optional: true

end
```

**section.rb (model):**

```
class Section < Component

  # == Associations ==========================
  has_many :components,
    class_name: 'Component',
    foreign_key: :component_id,
    dependent: :destroy

end
```

**component_controller.rb:**

```
  before_action :load_project
  before_action :load_scope  

  def index
    components = paginate @scope, per_page: per_page
    data = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(
      components,
      each_serializer: ComponentSerializer
    )
    render_response(:ok, { data: data })
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render_response(:not_found, { resource: "Project/Lesson" })
  end

  def load_scope
    @scope = @project.components
    @scope = @scope.order("position")
  end

  def load_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render_response(:not_found, { resource: "Project/Lesson" })
  end
```

Comment: Put the controller returning the data.

Comment: @Syl updated to include controller